Superset Apache configuration in Google Cloud – SSL
I've deployed Superset through https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/superset?project=debrieft-dev. All works fine apart from assigning custom certificate. I created a Google-managed certificate, and updated Load Balancer's frontend to take use of it. It worked for some time, but then it changed the certificate back again, to the temporary, self-managed one that was initially created when deploying the marketplace app.
How can one update the Superset so it uses Google Managed certificate?
